# The emulator do not work

Tags: android, eclipse

I am learning to develop Android applications and have come across a problem in my first project. I am following a tutorial  to create an app that will allow the user to type in some text, hit a button and then the app will output that text. I have written the code and have recieved no errors, but whenever I run the app on the emulator, it says "Unfortunately, (app name) has stopped. Here is the log cat:

Think the problem is here, but dont know what to do to fix it.

04-02 09:24:00.780: E/AndroidRuntime(861): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

And i don't know how to post code right in here*

```
          package com.smorgasbord;

   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Toast;


  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmatratt);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test if it works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
    });



   }    
   }
```

Comment: paste the code in pastebin then

Comment: Posting code: copy code, paste code, select code, Ctrl+K to apply formatting to code.

Comment: It is not the emulator that is not working, rather the code of the application is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That might be because you might have not linked your Widgets.

just give this in your `onCreate` method

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: @user3488852: instead of extending `ActionBarActivity` use `Activity`

Comment: Still same problem when i add Activity insted of ActionBarActivity

Comment: @user3488852 : can you post your full error log.
and have you tried to change the `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` to `import android.app.Activity;` when extending `extends Activity`